# "Error: initrd too big" no boot in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2

After a reboot of the remote server, the error started to appear just after the grub console and Ubuntu don't boot.
Ubuntu version 16.04.
Server with 64 gb of RAM.
I'm a newbie in this topics, any help is welcome.

[ls -al /boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB81R.png)

I have not been able to load previous kernels, the same error is reported.

Recovery mode error:
[Recovery mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiT64.jpg)

Also adding some more information from PTUUID
[PTUUID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jbNZ.png)

Comment: Did you check your BIOS/UEFI settings for disabling the memory hole remapping? e.g. maybe under Advanced -> Advanced Chipset Features -> Memory Hole Remapping (from bug 429898).

Comment: If you're able to boot to Recovery Mode, and get to a console/tty/root window, you can try `sudo update-initramfs -c` to rebuild your /boot/initrd.img* file. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @ubfan I have read about that fix, but I was not able to find the option in my bios, also this happened from one day working all fine to the next day having the error and the kernel or the boot was not toched directly or in propose. I will try to find the option again.

Comment: @heynnema I'm going to try that. I cannot enter recovery mode, but I can enter using liveCD, I can do what you propose from there?

Comment: @heynnema I got the following: update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-43
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.15.0-43
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-43: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
mkinitramfs: MODULES dep requires mounted sysfs on /sys
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-43 with 1.

Comment: @heynnema Finally I got it working (the command). But after recreating initramfs, the error of initrd is too  big persists.

Comment: @JamieArjona if you were booted to the Live DVD, then this command wouldn't work. Are you able to boot previous kernels on your server? If so, we can change the command slightly and then it should work. Edit your question with the output of `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: @heynnema I have improved the question with the output from ls -al /boot (did it from chroot inside liveCD). And no, I'm getting the same error using other kernels.

Comment: @JamieArjona are you able to run `memtest` from either the GRUB menu, or from the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? If so, make sure that it sees all 64G RAM, and run at least one full pass to assure that your RAM is good.

Comment: @heynnema In progress. So far it recognizes the 64GB of RAM. The process will take some hours, I will let the memtest until tomorrow.

Comment: @heynnema So, bad news, no errors from memtest.

Comment: @JamieArjona good news, actually. I've added a quick answer to help you run an fsck on your file system. Report back.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

memtest ran clean on 64GB RAM.

Lets check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Entering in recovery mode the following appeared, maybe is new information, I add a picture in the question.

Comment: fsck from live cd found a dirty bit on the disk, after solving that, no more errors and the problem persists.

Comment: @JamieArjona Is this in a virtual environment? Is ask because I see VFS. But then again, I also see hardware for nvme0n1p1. Your disk looks like it's corrupt. Do you know what brand/model your SSD is? If so, have you checked for a firmware update? Many early SSDs need to be updated. I also see sdb... looks like a RAID member? Please describe your disk configuration. Do you know how to check the SMART status of your disk(s)?

Comment: Is not a virtual environment. I have the following disk configuration: 1 Samsung 960 EVO NVMe M.2 SSD PCI-e 500GB that holds the OS and a 2 TB raid (did via software, raid 1 if I don't remember bad) where I have a database and the home folders. I have not checked for firmware updates in a long time. The server has now just 1 year old. I will check smart, I didn't did that never before but it doesn't seems complicated

Comment: @JamieArjona Download the Samsung tool at https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was not able to fix the error, so I reinstalled the kernel.

Talking with a colleague another thing that I tried is to fix the error using the tool BootRepair. The tool found some errors and seems that fixed something, but the original error (initrd too big) persisted. After that, I was exhausted and tired so I decided to reinstall it.

Thank you all, specially @heynnema.

After the reinstall all is working again.